# Disabling Windows CE Console on Handheld

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

Does anyone know how to disable the Windows CE Console on a Windows Mobile v5.0 handheld device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the registry on the device. PHM Regedit is a free tool that lets you do this.

Change the following key to 0xFFFFFFFF:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\Console\OutputTo
```

More here: https://meeting.uni.lu/andre.stemper/startcmd.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Remote Registry Editor and set the value of this key to something other than zero (such as 0xFFFFFFFF)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\Console\OutputTo
```